# Different Color for Char and String in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, color-scheme

I am looking to have `Eclipse` display a blue color when I am using `Strings` and a different color when using chars. I have already tried going to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring` and Changing the color for Strings, but when I click Apply and Ok, the Chars also change to the new color.

Is there any way to have a unique color exclusively for chars?

Comment: I dont think so, since they share the same attribute